# Multiple React Apps in one Project (Gitlab CI)

Tags: npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci, yarnpkg

I have multiple react apps in my project and want to build them in a gitlab pipeline.
I have to keep multiple single react apps. I can not compose them into one single react app.
So my problem is:
at the moment the gitlab job takes very long because I have to run yarn install in each react app I think.

my gitlab-ci.yml snippet looks like this:

```
script:
    - cd react
    - for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && pwd && yarn install && yarn build); done
```

Is there any better way than to do 'yarn install' in each react app which results in a node_modules folder for each single react app?

Can you cache the node_modules folder between gitlab jobs so the yarn install will use the cached version and updates it if necessary?

Or can you place the node_modules folder in a location where all react apps will get their dependencies from? So the same modules wont be downloaded again and again in the same gitlab job?

I am not familiar with gitlab CI CD and especially not with gitlab CI caching

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/ appears to be exactly what you need.